# Proper permissions on SFTP upload and download subdirectories in a user's home directory?

Tags: permissions, users, sftp, openssh

I have a server running OpenSSH. I've setup an SFTP server that users can log into. I have created user `userName` with a folder at `/sftp/userName` with permissions of `555` and owner `root`. This folder has two subfolders, `upload` and `download` with permissions of `755` and `555` respectively. Both subfolders are owned by `userName`. I have setup my server to prevent userName from accessing anything outside of `/sftp/userName` and this folder acts as the root directory when userName is logged in.

My goals:

- allow userName to login and see the `download` and `upload` folders within `/sftp/userName`.
- prevent userName from uploading or downloading anything in the folder `/sftp/userName`.
- allow userName to enter into `download` and download files but not upload files.
- allow userName to enter into `upload` and upload/download/delete files.

All of this behavior works correctly and seems like a good setup for my situation.

My problem is that userName can change permissions on the `upload` and `download` folders using `chmod xxx`.

**Questions:**

How can I prevent userName from making changes to folder permissions on `upload` and `download`?

Are there other gotchas with my setup that I should be aware of?

Comment: I'd learn AppArmor because that's the sort of thing it is intended for. SELinux is also worth mention, but I think there is a much higher ramp-up cost and you don't mention government agency approval as a need.

Comment: What is the meaning of `acts as the root directory when userName is logged in`?  Does `userName` log in via `ftp` or `ssh` or what?